# Connection refused - Docker-compose - SpringBoot, Angular, Postgres

Tags: angular, postgresql, spring-boot, docker-compose

I want to create a docker-compose with backend: Spring Boot, frontend: Angular, and Postgresql DB.
I tried everything on the internet, but it's not working.
It's connecting and after a few seconds it says connection refused

My Docker-Compose:

```
version: '3'

 services:

  database:
  image: postgres:13.3
  container_name: database
  environment:
   POSTGRES_DB: "fahrzeuge_verwalten"
   POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
   POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
  ports:
   - 5432:5432
  networks:
   - backendNetwork

  springapi:
   image: openjdk:11-jre-slim
   container_name: springapi

   ports:
    - 8080:8080
   depends_on:
    - database
   volumes:
    - ./target/fahrzeugverwaltung-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/app.jar
   command: ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
   networks:
    - backendNetwork
    - frontendNetwork

 angular:
  image: nginx:alpine
  container_name: angular
  ports:
   - 4200:80
  depends_on:
   - springapi
  volumes:
   - ./nginx.conf:/Users/betu/Documents/Docker-Compose/nginx.conf
   - ./carManagement/dist/carManagement/:/usr/share/nginx/html
  networks:
   - frontendNetwork


volumes:
 fahrzeugverwaltungData:

networks:
 backendNetwork:
 frontendNetwork:
```

Application Properties:

```
 spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/fahrzeuge_verwalten
 spring.datasource.username=postgres
 spring.datasource.password=postgres

 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

 spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

 spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db.changelog/changelog-master.yaml
```

And the Message:

```
C:\Users\betu\Documents\Git- 
Proj\fahrzeug_verwaltung\fahrzeugverwaltung\src\main\resources\db.changelog>docker-compose up
Creating network "fahrzeugverwaltung_backendNetwork" with the default driver
Creating network "fahrzeugverwaltung_frontendNetwork" with the default driver
Creating database ... done
Creating springapi ... done
Creating angular   ... done
Attaching to database, springapi, angular
angular      | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to 
perform configuration
angular      | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
angular      | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by- 
default.sh
angular      | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of 
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
database     | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
database     | This user must also own the server process.
database     |
database     | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
database     | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
database     | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
database     |
database     | Data page checksums are disabled.
database     |
database     | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
database     | creating subdirectories ... ok
database     | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
database     | selecting default max_connections ... 100
database     | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
database     | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
database     | creating configuration files ... ok
database     | running bootstrap script ... ok
database     | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
database     | syncing data to disk ... ok
database     |
database     |
database     | Success. You can now start the database server using:
database     |
database     |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
database     |
database     | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
database     | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
database     | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
database     | waiting for server to start....2021-07-09 16:13:08.180 UTC [48] LOG:  starting 
 PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-lin
 ux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
database     | 2021-07-09 16:13:08.184 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket 
 "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
database     | 2021-07-09 16:13:08.194 UTC [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021- 
 07-09 16:13:07 UTC
database     | 2021-07-09 16:13:08.199 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept 
 connections
database     |  done
database     | server started
database     | CREATE DATABASE
database     |
database     |
database     | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
database     |
database     | 2021-07-09 16:13:08.460 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
database     | waiting for server to shut down....2021-07-09 16:13:08.463 UTC [48] LOG:  
   aborting any active transactions
database     | 2021-07-09 16:13:08.464 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication 
  launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
database     | 2021-07-09 16:13:08.464 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down
database     | 2021-07-09 16:13:08.481 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
database     |  done
database     | server stopped
database     |
database     | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
database     |
database     | 2021-07-09 16:13:08.599 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3- 
  1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian
  8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
database     | 2021-07-09 16:13:08.599 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 
  5432
angular      | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in 
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
database     | 2021-07-09 16:13:08.599 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
database     | 2021-07-09 16:13:08.608 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket 
  "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
database     | 2021-07-09 16:13:08.619 UTC [76] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021- 
  07-09 16:13:08 UTC
database     | 2021-07-09 16:13:08.624 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept 
  connections
angular      | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on- 
  templates.sh
angular      | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker- 
  processes.sh
angular      | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.21.1
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.3.1 20210424 (Alpine 
 10.3.1_git20210424)
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 35
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 36
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 37
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 38
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 39
angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:11 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 40
springapi    |
springapi    |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
springapi    |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
springapi    | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
springapi    |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
springapi    |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
springapi    |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
springapi    |  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.1)
springapi    |
springapi    | HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.2.0.Final
springapi    | Starting FahrzeugverwaltungApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.11 on 
    ae616c1ba89f with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
springapi    | No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
springapi    | Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
springapi    | Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 369 ms. Found 1 JPA repository 
  interfaces.
springapi    | Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
springapi    | Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
springapi    | Starting service [Tomcat]
springapi    | Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.46]
springapi    | Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
springapi    | Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7452 ms
  angular      | 2021/07/09 16:13:22 [error] 33#33: *1 directory index of 
  "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.32.1, server: localhost,
  request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:4200"
angular      | 192.168.32.1 - - [09/Jul/2021:16:13:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 555 "-" 
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36
  (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36" "-"
springapi    | HikariPool-1 - Starting...
springapi    | HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
springapi    | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check 
  that the hostname and port are correct and that the postma
  ster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
springapi    |  at 
 org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl( 
 ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303)
springapi    |  at 
 org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
springapi    |  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
springapi    |  at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
springapi    |  at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
springapi    |  at 
 com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
springapi    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
springapi    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
springapi    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
springapi    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
springapi    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
springapi    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
springapi    |  at 
 liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:272)
springapi    |  at 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory. 
  invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.jav
   a:1845)
springapi    |  at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean( 
 AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1
 782)
springapi    |  at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean( 
 AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
springapi    |  at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean( 
 AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
springapi    |  at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0( 
 AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
springapi    |  at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton( 
 DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean( 
  AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean( 
  AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean( 
  AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean( 
  AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean( 
  AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
springapi    |  at 
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext. 
 finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
springapi    |  at 
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh 
 (AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
springapi    |  at 
 org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh( 
 ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
springapi    |  at 
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
springapi    |  at 
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
springapi    |  at com.webapp.fahrzeugverwaltung.FahrzeugverwaltungApplication.main( 
  FahrzeugverwaltungApplication.java:10)
springapi    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native 
  Method)
springapi    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown 
  Source)
springapi    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown 
 Source)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
springapi    |  at 
 org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
springapi    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
springapi    |  at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
springapi    |  at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
springapi    |  at 
  org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
springapi    |  at 
  org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl( 
  ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
springapi    |  ... 40 common frames omitted
springapi    | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh 
  attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
  : Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource 
  [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$
  LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
  liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLExce
  ption: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct 
  and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
springapi    | Stopping service [Tomcat]
springapi    |
springapi    |
springapi    | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your 
  application with 'debug' enabled.
springapi    | Application run failed
springapi    | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
   with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/sp
   ringframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$ 
   LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception
   is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 
   127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are
   correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
springapi    |  at 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory. 
  initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1 786)
springapi    |  at 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory. 
  doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602 )
springapi    |  at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory. 
 createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
springapi    |  at 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0( 
  AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
springapi    |  at 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton( 
  DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean( 
  AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean( 
  AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean( 
  AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean( 
  AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean( 
  AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext. 
  finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh( 
  AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
springapi    |  at 
  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext. 
  refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
springapi    |  at 
  org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
springapi    |  at 
  org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
springapi    |  at com.webapp.fahrzeugverwaltung.FahrzeugverwaltungApplication.main( 
  FahrzeugverwaltungApplication.java:10)
springapi    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native 
  Method)
springapi    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown 
  Source)
springapi    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown 
  Source)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
springapi    |  at 
  org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
springapi    |  at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
springapi    | Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the
 hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
springapi    |  at 
  liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:277)
springapi    |  at 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory. 
  invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.jav
  a:1845)
springapi    |  at 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean( 
  AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1 782)
springapi    |  ... 26 common frames omitted
springapi    | Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 
  refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that
  the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
springapi    |  at 
  org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl( 
  ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303)
springapi    |  at 
   org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
springapi    |  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
springapi    |  at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
springapi    |  at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
springapi    |  at 
  com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
springapi    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
springapi    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
springapi    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
springapi    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
springapi    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
springapi    |  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
springapi    |  at 
  liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:272)
springapi    |  ... 28 common frames omitted
springapi    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
springapi    |  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
springapi    |  at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
springapi    |  at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
springapi    |  at 
  org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
springapi    |  at 
  org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl( 
  ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
springapi    |  ... 40 common frames omitted
springapi exited with code 1
```

I'm a beginner, so can anybody please help me with this problem?

Comment: Try spinning up only the Postgres image? it's running into bean creation exception because of Postgres refusing connection. Once Postgres is up, visit localhost:5432 and check if it's up and responding fine.

Comment: yes, that works. but with the other 2 services it's not

Answer (score 0):

In you application properties file

you have

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/fahrzeuge_verwalten
```

this should be

```
 spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://locahost:5432/fahrzeuge_verwalten
```

or better

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/fahrzeuge_verwalten
```

if you're connected through VPN, do ipconfig in command prompt and use VPN IPV4 IP address in place of localhost in case if localhost didn't work or so.